# Sitecore create item programmatically with over 100 fields using GlassMapper

Tags: orm, sitecore, glass-mapper

I need to write a job to create 1000s of items in Sitecore.
As there are 100s fields in my Sitecore Data Template I would like to avoid repeating the below code line for each field in my code:

`newItem.Fields["Title"].Value = "NewValue1";`

Can I use GlassMapper (which I believe needs to run in the MVC context) or an equivalent to do this instead?

Comment: You want to avoid what? What initiates the creation of these items?

Comment: I want to avoid repeating the .Fields[FieldName].Value a 100 times since there are 100 fields in the Sitecore Template Item

Comment: What would be the benefit of using glass mapper?

Comment: GlassMapper will only generate strongly typed structs or classes for the template data or template models. You still have to do the assignment manually.

Answer (score 1):

You have to map at least once even if it 100s of fields. You do not need to repeat that for 1000s of items. You should get all 1000 sourceObjects in a list and iterate over it to map its properties to Item fields.

```
 // Iterate through 1000s of items to create
foreach(var sourceObject in SourceObjects)
{
    var newItem = New Item();
    newItem.Fields["Title"].Value = sourceObject.Title;
    // Field mapping for rest 99 fields
}
```